# how to avoid rejected value [] issue in spring form submission

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have two dates in form submission in Spring 3 + Hibernate.
@Column(name = "FinStartDate")
    private Date finStartDate;

```
@Column(name = "FinEndDate")
private Date finEndDate;
```

I'm display/hide dates on the basis of some criteria. When the dates are hidden and submit the form, the following errors

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'register' on field 'obj.finEndDate': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch]
```

How to avoid the issue.

Comment: It looks like the error that I'm trying to resolve. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828363/client-sending-string-instead-of-bigdecimal-to-server-on-update. How you resolved it?

Answer (score 2):

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date finEndDate;
```

Maybe, you should use serializer/deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you miss a formatter to convert the date String to a Date object.

You can try to annotate your field

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

or to declare a initbinder in your controller like :

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}
```

Or you can declare a formatter in you mvc configuration file that will format every Date object your application is binding to.

Comment: actually i need not format the String, but need to avoid the date checking if i not pass the value when it is hidden.

Comment: So when you hide your input also disable it, disabled input value won't be posted, so spring won't try to bind it.

Comment: But in my case spring shows  'obj.finEndDate': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch] when it is disabled. I'm receiving values in Controller vai @ModelAttribute() annotation

Answer (score 0):

Add @DateTimeFormat annotation for following way. If not working update date format. **(MM-dd-yyyy, dd-MM-yyyy)**

```
@Column(name = "FinEndDate")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date finEndDate;
```