# Client sending String[] instead of BigDecimal to server on update

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring, jsp

When is a **new record** works **peacefully**, **the problem** is on **update**.

I have a **A** object that is the master, another **B** object that is an `ArrayList` and detail of master **A** and for last an **C** object that is an `ArrayList` and detail of **B** object.

When I send the information to the server and the `index` of **B object is equal** 0 and the detail which is the **C** object isn't null works well without complain to convert `String[]` to `BigDecimal`.

But when I send to the server the information and the `index` of object **B is higher** than 0 and the detail that is **C** object isn't null is accusing that is trying to convert `String[]` to `BigDecimal` and returns error.

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
>   Field error in object 'A' on field 'B[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtWTG.png).C[0].attribute': rejected value [190.67,190.67]; ...

As defined the element in my **JSP File** that I fill using AngularJS when the user click to create a new item in C object:

```
name='B[{{B.index}}].C[{{C.index}}].attribute'
```

As defined in the model:

```
@Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE")
@NotNull(message = "{validate.required.attribute}")
@NumberFormat(pattern = "0.00")
private BigDecimal attribute;
```

Print screens of the JavaScript in **submit event** of the **form**:

[image: AngularJS objects]

[image]

Any solution for this problem? Apparently I believe that the definition in **name** attribute to generate correctly the objects on server layer is correct, even more that is saving in the database when is a new record, the problem occurs when is updating the form and when the **B** object have the **C** object that isn't be null and is in an index higher than 0 causing the appearence of a String vector in the attribute as you realized through the error message given that it seems that was multiplied for many elements that have in **B** object, or **B** detail.

The question is, how I can fix it being that is apparently correct?

For answer this question in portuguese I create another question in Portuguese Stackoverflow, [click here to open the link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89395/cliente-enviando-string-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-bigdecimal-para-servidor-ao-alterar).

Para responder esta questão em português eu criei outra questão no Stackoverflow Português, [clique aqui para abrir o link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89395/cliente-enviando-string-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-bigdecimal-para-servidor-ao-alterar).